# How do I display commas in countdown ticker?

Tags: javascript, css, timer

I need for this to display commas and I'm having trouble figuring that out. Any help?
I have tried a couple of things but the count up is not the same it starts out very slow and with a lot less digits than I need it to.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('.counter-ticker').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
      countTo = $this.attr('data-count');

    $({
      countNum: $this.text()
    }).animate({
        countNum: countTo
      },

      {

        duration: 3000000000,
        easing: 'linear',
        step: function () {
          $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
        },
        complete: function () {
          $this.text(this.countNum);
          //alert('finished');
        }
      });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use built-in code, you can use toLocaleString() with minimumFractionDigits.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString